# MSAL - Network request failed. Please check network trace to determine root cause

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-oauth

I am trying to use MSAL for node.js for OAuth 2.0 authentication, and I'm getting an error when calling `acquireTokenByAuthCode`.

```
Network request failed. Please check network trace to determine root cause. | Fetch client threw: Error: HTTP status code 400 | Attempted to reach: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Client instance:

```
const msal = new ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.MS_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.MS_SECRET,
        authority: process.env.MS_AUTHORITY
    }
})
```

Login route:

```
const uri = await msal.getAuthCodeUrl({
  responseMode: 'query',
  redirectUri: `${process.env.APP_URI}/auth/code`,
  scopes: ['user.read']
});
res.redirect(uri);
```

Token route (/auth/code):

```
try {
  const {
    accessToken,
  } = await msal.acquireTokenByCode({
    scopes: ['user.read'],
    code: req.query.code,
    redirectUri: `${process.env.APP_URI}/auth/code`,
  });
  res.cookie('token', accessToken);
  res.redirect('/');
}
catch(e) {
  res.status(401).send(e);
}
```

I can retrieve an auth code just fine, but I get the error when trying to get the token in the last snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The Application was just missing the `openid` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `clientSecret` is correct. I just had this same issue and realized I was using the ID of the secret as opposed to the actual secret itself.

Comment: No the secret is right. I'm fairly certain though that the secret isn't even needed if you're just getting permission on behalf of the user signing in. I added the secret later just to test, but the docs don't even say it's required.